# User-resizable Codemirror instance

Tags: codemirror

does anybody know if it's possible to manually resize a Codemirror textbox? What I mean is for example Firefox has this feature that you can manually drag a textarea item - but via Codemirror this doesn't work.

No cross-compatible browser support is needed, if we can find something only for Firefox, that's fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write some code -- add a handle element, overlay it on the bottom-right corner, and register handlers that call the `.setSize` method on your editor instance when the element is dragged.

Comment: Something along the lines of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/rs2L2vtb/2/) :-)